# Executing external .js file from HTML page, by sending input.xml and getting output.xml from external.js file

Tags: javascript, html, xml

How to execute a external Javascript file from html page.
I need to send input to .js file 
And I also need to get output from external .js file.

I am thinking like building a input.xml file with my inputs as nodes in it.
I will execute the external .js file by sending my input.xml file.
My external .js file will parse my input.xml and perform the function using my inputs.
External .js will build the Output.xml file with results as a nodes in it.
My html page needs to parse the Output.xml and display the results in the html page.

I can do all the other stuff, but I couldn't figure how to execute the external .js file by sending my input.xml and read Output.xml from .js file.

Any ideas for this kind of design??

Comment: `<script src="/path/to/external.js">`?

Comment: I need to execute it by sending my input.xml and read the output.xml from the external.js file.

Answer (score 0):

path/to/file.js:

```
function externalfunction(input) {
    //stuff
};
```

index.html:

```
<script src="path/to/file.js"></script>
<script>
var somevar = externalfunction(someothervar);
</script>
```

The external script `path/to/file.js` is included in index.html, so the function defined in it is accessible. The function is then called.

Comment: I need to execute it by sending my input.xml and read the output.xml from the external.js file.

Comment: @Dude My question is actually how execute the external.js file from HTML page and send my inputs to that .js file as input.xml and read the output.xml from .js file and display in my HTML page.     Something like Execute( external.js, input.xml) and read the output from it like Execute.output or something.                       Sorry about my English and vocabulary.

Comment: @Dude I still couldn't figure out how can I pass my input.xml to path/to/file.js. Could you please explain in detail.

Comment: @Powered I thot you figured that out… How is the xml stored? Is it a tag somewhere in your html? iFrame? String in a variable already in the js?